# Should use indulging or wallowing

Tags: vocabulary

Which one should be correct?After a tiring soccer practice, Jack rewarded himself by indulging or wallowing in a box of doughnuts.
Thank you.

Comment: I see that **indulge** is more correct and suitable, as you are referring to a person's situation. When **wallow** is famous for describing animals species. References: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indulging AND https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wallow

Comment: If Jack indulged in a box of doughnuts, he allowed himself the luxury of consuming them. If he wallowed in them, he rolled about in the box (like an elephant or hippo in a pool).

Answer (score 1):

> After a tiring soccer practice, Jack rewarded himself by **indulging** in a box of doughnuts (with sprinkles).

Since this refers to a positive reinforcement, use *indulge*.

If in a negative sense, use *wallow*:

> Jack tripped and fell, and caused his team to lose the game. All he could do now is *wallow* in his misery.

See [*wallow*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wallow):

> 1. *verb*
>      If you say that someone is **wallowing** in an unpleasant situation, you are criticizing them for being deliberately unhappy.